# Java EE Application Directory Best Practice Question

Tags: java, web-applications, netbeans

I am relatively new at Java EE and have just gotten familiar with the traditional application directory structure (which includes the BUILD, DIST, NBPROJECT, SRC, and WEB folders). I was wondering: if my application requires to use some resources/assets (such as images or pdfs) on the server, in which of the 5 folders listed above should I place those resources? I think I can technically place them anywhere, as long as I reference the files correctly, but not sure what the common best practice is for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would usually include static content e.g. images or PDFs which need to be read by http requests in WebContent e.g. if my-web is your WAR project:

```
my-web/WebContent/images
my-web/WebContent/scripts
my-web/WebContent/misc
```

This means you can access using for example:

```
/my-web/images/bob.jpg
/my-web/scripts/bob.js
/my-web/misc/bob.pdf
```

Storing the files here allows public access.  I will quote this from the [Eclipse help pages](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user/topics/ccwebprj.html):

> The Web content folder represents the
>   contents of the WAR file that will be
>   deployed to the server. Any files not
>   under the Web content folder are
>   considered development-time resources
>   (for example, .java files, .sql files,
>   and .mif files), and are not deployed
>   when the project is unit tested or
>   published.

Comment: I am using Netbeans and do not see a WebContent folder. Do I need to create one?? All I see inside the WEB directory is META-INF, WEB-INF, and index.jsp

Comment: I'm not a NetBeans user.  But I believe you add folders and static content in the Web Pages folder.  So you may have MyWebProject/WEB-INF.  Add your files to MyWebProject/images, MyWebProject/scripts, MyWebProject/misc.  NetBeans may show a folder called "Web Pages", so drop your folders and content into that.

Comment: Gotchya! Thank you.. Out of curiosity, just realized that inside the DIST and WEB directories, the content that is currently there is identical. What's the reason for that?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure - is the DIST directory just where the output files are copied to (so WEB holds the master and DIST is just a copy).  Maybe you could look at the file system to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about how the assets get delivered to the client before deciding where to put them. Resources such as ccs and static html pages are retrieved by the client using separate HTTP calls, so they need to be in a place that is accessible. In your case, I'd say they have to be at the level of index.jsp, or in subdirectories at that level. If you put them in WEB-INF, they will be inacessible from the outside world. You could *possibly* put them in META-INF but it would be an unusual use of that directory.